# Sending trait objects between threads in Rust

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'd like to send a trait object between threads, but can't figure out if it's possible. It seems like it might not be, as they apparently do not fulfill the `Send` trait.

The following code demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
use std::{
    sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender},
    thread,
};

trait Bar {
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct Foo {
    foo: i32,
}

impl Bar for Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("foo: {}", self.foo);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Box::new(Foo { foo: 1 }) as Box<dyn Bar>;

    let (tx, rx): (Sender<Box<dyn Bar>>, Receiver<Box<dyn Bar>>) = channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        tx.send(foo).unwrap();
    });

    let sent = rx.recv().unwrap();

    sent.bar();
}
```

This fails with the following message:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn Bar` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:25:5
    |
25  |     thread::spawn(move || {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn Bar` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn Bar`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<dyn Bar>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<dyn Bar>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:25:19: 27:6 tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::boxed::Box<dyn Bar>>, foo:std::boxed::Box<dyn Bar>]`
```

Trying to send a plain, unboxed trait object results in a bunch of other errors, mostly complaining about not fulfilling `Send + Sized`.

I'm still fairly new to Rust, so I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing, but I get the impression that there isn't a way to convince the compiler to make the trait object `Send`.

If it isn't currently possible, is there any work currently under way that may allow for this in the future?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's possible. You can add a `Send` constraint to a trait object like this:

```
let foo = Box::new(Foo { foo: 1 }) as Box<dyn Bar + Send>;

let (tx, rx): (Sender<Box<dyn Bar + Send>>, Receiver<Box<dyn Bar + Send>>) = channel();
```

Comment: Oh, huh, that's simple enough. I guess I didn't quite understand how trait objects were actually handled. So it's not the trait that has a kind, it's the underlying object, right? So you just have to let the compiler know that the box is holding something with the trait, which also happens to fulfill `Send`. I think I get it now.

Comment: This might be useful to someone: In my case, I also required `Sync` trait, as in `Box<dyn Bar + Send + Sync>`. (My use case was for a web server using [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) library).

Comment: I found the simplest thing was to require `Send` on all implementations of my trait like this: `trait Bar : Send { ...`. Obviously you may not want to do that if you might have some uses that don't require `Send`.