# Why does an `impl Trait` return value implement Send while `Box<dyn Trait>` does not?

Tags: rust, traits

The solution from [How do I store a variable of type `impl Trait` in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035366/how-do-i-store-a-variable-of-type-impl-trait-in-a-struct) suggests creating a `Future` trait object. Doing that in my real code generates an error that the type is not `Send`, but the only difference between the working and non working version is the presence or absence of the cast to `dyn Future`.

Why does the compiler see these as different and how do I resolve the problem?

Here's a simplified version of the problem:

```
use std::future::Future;

fn uses_impl_trait() -> impl Future<Output = i32> {
    async { 42 }
}

fn uses_trait_object() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = i32>> {
    Box::new(async { 42 })
}

fn requires_send<T: Send>(_: T) {}

fn example() {
    requires_send(uses_impl_trait()); // Works
    requires_send(uses_trait_object()); // Fails
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `dyn std::future::Future<Output = i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:15:19
   |
11 | fn requires_send<T: Send>(_: T) {}
   |    -------------    ---- required by this bound in `requires_send`
...
15 |     requires_send(uses_trait_object());
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn std::future::Future<Output = i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn std::future::Future<Output = i32>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<dyn std::future::Future<Output = i32>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output = i32>>`
```

From [Sending trait objects between threads in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25649423/155423), I already know that I can change the trait object to `Box<dyn Future<Output = i32> + Send>`, but **why** does this difference exist?

Comment: Fair enough. I've drastically simplified and generalized the question to focus on the why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ergonomic reasons. [RFC 1522, conservative impl trait](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1522-conservative-impl-trait.html), specifically discusses this design decision:

> OIBITs leak through an abstract return type. This might be considered controversial, since
>   it effectively opens a channel where the result of function-local type inference affects
>   item-level API, but has been deemed worth it for the following reasons:
>
> - Ergonomics: Trait objects already have the issue of explicitly needing to
>     declare `Send`/`Sync`-ability, and not extending this problem to abstract
>     return types is desirable. In practice, most uses of this feature would have
>     to add explicit bounds for OIBITS if they wanted to be maximally usable.
> - Low real change, since the situation already somewhat exists on structs with private fields:
>
>   - In both cases, a change to the private implementation might change whether a OIBIT is
>       implemented or not.
>   - In both cases, the existence of OIBIT impls is not visible without documentation tools
>   - In both cases, you can only assert the existence of OIBIT impls
>       by adding explicit trait bounds either to the API or to the crate's test suite.
>
> In fact, a large part of the point of OIBITs in the first place was to cut
>   across abstraction barriers and provide information about a type without the
>   type's author having to explicitly opt in.
>
> This means, however, that it has to be considered a silent breaking change to
>   change a function with an abstract return type in a way that removes OIBIT impls,
>   which might be a problem. (As noted above, this is already the case for `struct`
>   definitions.)
>
> But since the number of used OIBITs is relatively small, deducing the return type
>   in a function body and reasoning about whether such a breakage will occur has
>   been deemed as a manageable amount of work.

See also:

- [What is an auto trait in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49710852/155423)